# Printing PDF file specific pages using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, printing

Windows allows us to print specific PDF files manually from the printing options. I only need a PDF reader (**which can be free**) to open the file, then print it by entering specific page numbers. However I couldn't find doing this process programmatically **without using any third party licensed PDF program or library**.

I am looking way to do this using MS VBA 2003. Is it possible?

Comment: If you have Word 2013 you may be able to create an instance of word, open the document, and print selected pages there.  Apparently Word 2013 will open a PDF, but I don't have it to try myself.

Comment: @MattB I loved your solution however I do not have word 2013. I checked if word 2003 can open PDF files and got disappointed from the result.

Comment: I know there is a plug in for older versions of word to allow you to save pdf files.  You might check for a plug in that would allow you to open them.

Comment: @MattB Thanks for your suggestion, i could only find addons for saving a as a pdf file as you said, but none for opening.

Comment: You may be out of luck without spending a few bucks then.  I really think getting Word 2013 is going to be your best solution if not the only solution in this case.  There may be something out there though.  Keep digging.  Bottom line is that you need an app that can open and print PDF documents which is Com visible, and to the best of my knowledge Word 2013 seems to be the only horse in that race.

Comment: @MattB the problem is the access database is shared by 100-200 computers. If I add a simple code that requires licensing, it will end up spending more than few bucks. I found another solution by creating an access button to invoke an exe file that is written in C or C# from the command prompt. I think I will be able to find some libraries on C or C# about printing specific pages.

Comment: You may have an option with IE.  I'm looking into it.

Comment: Eh, never mind.  Doesn't look like that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what I aimed by using an COM exposed C# application.

The PDF printing library was easy to find as a C# .NET project, therefore I produced my own .dll file by creating a .NET C# Class library project. In this application, I used the library called PdfSharp which is opensource. I wrote my code in order to expose it to COM.

After I registered my produced .dll and created a .tlb file, I referenced this .tlb file to my Access Visual Basic editor. Voila! it worked perfect.